# How to get just the date part of getdate()?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table that has a CreationDate field.

I have `getdate()` in the computed column specification formula.

I would like to know how to get just the date portion, that is, '2012-08-24' instead of '2012-08-24 10:45:17.740'.

Comment: If this is SQL Server, which it looks like, you should use the SQL-server tag in addition to your current tags

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later

```
select convert(date, getdate())
```

Otherwise

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(),120)
```

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
select convert (date ,getdate())
```

or

```
select CAST (getdate() as DATE)
```

or

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(),121)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS float)) as datetime)
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,FLOOR(CONVERT(float,GETDATE())))
```